# Issue in taking screenshot in selenium while using chromedriver 73 for chrome version 73

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

When i tried to take screenshot of a webpage using selenium in python, i get error message `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000`.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
indi_url = 'http://www.google.com'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("--disable")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(indi_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.save_screenshot("new.png")
```

Error message:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I'm using Chrome version 73, chromedriver version 73.

Note: code was working fine (ie.screenshot)in lower version of chrome and chrome driver.

Help me out in fixing this issue for new version of chrome driver.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: It's a known issue, You can see in the following bugs reports https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/ZBEju24L5ww https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942023

Comment: @DebanjanB, updated question with code.

Comment: @Ryan Bowden, Any workaround for this?

Comment: @YakeshrajM Are you using Jenkins or any scheduler?

Comment: @DebanjanB it is a python file execution using pycharm IDE in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, your filename for screenshot does not match the template extensions .png

Here is an example how to make a screenshot.

Java:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshots\\example_screenshot.png"));
```

Python:

```
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

Comment: OP is using _Python_ possibly you have to refactor the _Java_ code into _Python_.

Comment: @Infern0 that won't be the issue, i guess because i have tried the same before, it worked fine before.
And getting the same error msg using "driver.screenshot("screenshot.png")"

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
  UserWarning: name used for saved screenshot does not match file type. It should end with a .png extension
"type. It should end with a .png extension", UserWarning)
```

...implies that the *Selenium-Python* client encountered an issue while invoking `get_screenshot_as_file()` method.

---

### get_screenshot_as_file()

[get_screenshot_as_file()](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L1053) saves a screenshot of the current window to a `PNG` image file. Returns `False` if there is any *IOError*, else returns `True`. Use full paths in your filename.

- Args:

  - filename: The full path you wish to save your screenshot to. This should end with a `.png` extension.
- Usage:

  ```
  driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/Screenshots/foo.png')
  ```
- Defination:

  ```
  if not filename.lower().endswith('.png'):
      warnings.warn("name used for saved screenshot does not match file "
                    "type. It should end with a `.png` extension", UserWarning)
  png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
  try:
      with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
          f.write(png)
  except IOError:
      return False
  finally:
      del png
  return True
  ```

---

### Analysis

As per the snapshot of the error stack trace:

[image: snapshot]

You have used the command as:

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('new.jpeg')
```

The issues were:

- The filename didn't end with `.png`
- The desired *full path of your filename* wasn't provided.

Even if you desire to use `save_screenshot()` this method in-turn invokes `get_screenshot_as_file(filename)`

---

### Solution

Create a directory within your project as `Screenshots` and provide the *absolute path* of the filename you desire for the screenshot while invoking either of the methods as follows:

- `driver.get_screenshot_as_file("./Screenshots/YakeshrajM.png")`
- `driver.save_screenshot("./Screenshots/YakeshrajM.png")`

---

### Update

Currently GAed ***Chrome v73*** have some issues and you may like to downgrade to ***Chrome v72***. You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Getting Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000 When we execute selenium scripts using Jenkins windows service mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373625/getting-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-600-000-when-we-execute-selen/55374585#55374585)
- [Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 while capturing screenshot using chromedriver and chrome through Jenkins on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364056/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000-while-capturing-screenshot-usi/55371396#55371396)

Comment: @YakeshrajM Did you get a chance to look into this solution?

Comment: facing same issue still..
As i already mentioned that code was working good with previous version of chrome and chrome driver and i was able to save the screenshots in '.jpg' format itself.. '.png' extension is just user warning message, which can be neglible.
As already told by Ryan Bowden it is an open issue in chrome and they are trying to fix it.
So waiting for the fix eagerly.

Comment: @YakeshrajM Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.