# Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 while capturing screenshot using chromedriver and chrome through Jenkins on Windows

Tags: windows, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome
Browser version: Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (32-bit)

I am running selenium cucumber BDD project where I am verifying title of one page. I am using extent-report version4. Project running successfully in local. But when i am running it through Jenkins, its failing while capturing screenshot and showing below error.

If i remove the surfire plugin from pom.xml then the TEST is not running via Jenkins.

In Execute Windows Batch command option of Jenkins i have given below command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CucumberBDDFramework
mvn test
```

TestRunner

```
    package com.accenture.TestRunner;

    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
    import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
    import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;


    /**
     * @author ajinkya.pande
     *
     */

    @CucumberOptions(
            features="./features/WhatIsBitcoin.feature",
            glue= {"com.accenture.StepDef"},
            tags= {"@ExtentReport"}, 
            dryRun = false
            )

    public class TestRunner {

        // Write following steps or Try to extend AbstractTestNGCucumberTests

        private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

        @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void setUpClass() throws Exception{ 
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }

        @Test(dataProvider = "features")
        public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
            testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
        }

        @DataProvider
        public Object [][] features(){
            return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
        }


        @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void tearDownClass() throws Exception{
            testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
        }

    }
```

StepDefinition

```
    package com.accenture.listeners;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    import com.accenture.Utility.Constants;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

    /**
     * @author ajinkya.pande
     *
     */

    public class ExtentReportListener extends Constants {

        public static ExtentHtmlReporter report = null;
        public static ExtentReports extent = null;
        public static ExtentTest test = null;

        public static ExtentReports setUp() {
            String reportLocation = "./Reports/Extent_Report.html";
            report = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportLocation);
            report.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Test Report");
            report.config().setReportName("Automation Test Report");
            report.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
            System.out.println("Extent Report location initialized . . .");
            report.start();

            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(report);
            extent.setSystemInfo("Application", "Youtube");
            extent.setSystemInfo("Operating System", System.getProperty("os.name"));
            extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
            System.out.println("System Info. set in Extent Report");
            return extent;
        }

        public static void testStepHandle(String teststatus, WebDriver driver, ExtentTest extenttest, Throwable throwable) {
            if (teststatus.equals("FAIL")) {

                extenttest.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case is Failed : ", ExtentColor.RED));
                extenttest.error(throwable.fillInStackTrace());

                try {
                    extenttest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (driver != null) {
                    driver.quit();
                }

                if (teststatus.equals("PASS")) {
                    extenttest.pass(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case is Passed : ", ExtentColor.GREEN));
                    try {
                        extenttest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        public static String captureScreenShot(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
            TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            File src = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String dest = SCRRENSHOT_PATH + getcurrentdateandtime() + ".png";
            File target = new File(dest);
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, target);
            return dest;
        }

        private static String getcurrentdateandtime() {
            String str = null;
            try {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                Date date = new Date();
                str = dateFormat.format(date);
                str = str.replace(" ", "").replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(":", "");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return str;
        }

    }
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>org.ajinkya.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>extent-reporting</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



       <build>
        <plugins>


    <!--       <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </plugin> -->


          <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <fork>1.7</fork>
              <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>


       <!--    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execute</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                </configuration>
            </execution>            
        </executions>
          </plugin> -->


           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.19.1</version>
              <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>testng.xml</suiteXmlFiles>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
      </build>












      <dependencies>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>



      <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.8</version>
    </dependency>


      <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


      </dependencies>



    </project>
```

Jenkins Log:

---

```
     T E S T S
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Running TestSuite
    Starting...............
    Extent Report location initialized . . .
    System Info. set in Extent Report
    Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 8950
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    Mar 26, 2019 11:15:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
    [1553622354.306][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
    [1553622354.307][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
    [1553622364.313][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.996
    [1553622374.336][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.998
    [1553622374.337][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
    [1553622384.337][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.998
    [1553622394.343][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
    [1553622394.344][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
    [1553622404.345][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.996

    Failed scenarios:
    ./features/WhatIsBitcoin.feature:3 # Scenario: Testing extent reports

    1 Scenarios (1 failed)
    4 Steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
    1m25.069s

    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.996
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
    System info: host: 'BDC11-L-FYK3VP2', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e3..., userDataDir: C:\windows\TEMP\scoped_dir1...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51833}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.86, webStorageEnabled: true}
    Session ID: 1b4d8402a8e29651ed2c7a773c11ca37
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:291)
        at com.accenture.listeners.ExtentReportListener.captureScreenShot(ExtentReportListener.java:81)
        at com.accenture.StepDef.WhatIsBitcoin.go_to_chrome(WhatIsBitcoin.java:47)
        at ?.When Go to chrome(./features/WhatIsBitcoin.feature:4)

    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 86.657 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
    feature(com.accenture.TestRunner.TestRunner)  Time elapsed: 85.109 sec  <<< FAILURE!
    cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 
    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.996
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
    System info: host: 'BDC11-L-FYK3VP2', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e3..., userDataDir: C:\windows\TEMP\scoped_dir1...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51833}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.86, webStorageEnabled: true}
    Session ID: 1b4d8402a8e29651ed2c7a773c11ca37
        at com.accenture.TestRunner.TestRunner.feature(TestRunner.java:42)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: 
    timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.996
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
    System info: host: 'BDC11-L-FYK3VP2', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e3..., userDataDir: C:\windows\TEMP\scoped_dir1...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51833}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.86, webStorageEnabled: true}
    Session ID: 1b4d8402a8e29651ed2c7a773c11ca37


    Results :

    Failed tests: 
      TestRunner.feature:42 » Cucumber org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout...

    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  01:33 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-26T23:16:45+05:30
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project extent-reporting: There are test failures.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CucumberBDDFramework\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems you are using **chromedriver=73.0.3683.68** and **chrome=73.0.3683.86** on **Windows OS**

John Chen (Owner - chromedriver) recently have confirmed that:

> We have confirmed issues with take screenshot when Chrome 73.0.3686.75 is started by a service (such as Jenkins or Task scheduler) on Windows. Please see https://crbug.com/942023 for more details. We apologize for any inconvenience caused by this.
>
> However, we haven't yet been able to observe similar issue on Linux, so we appreciate any help you can provide to enable us to reproduce the issue on Linux. We don't have access to TeamCity, but we have tested take screenshot using Docker image produced by Selenium (selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-lithium), and didn't find any problems.

[image: chromedriver73]

---

### Update

We were able to dig up the main issue. The main issue is not with *ChromeDriver v73.x* as such but with **Chrome v73.x** and John officially confirms it as:

> The root cause is indeed in Chrome 73.x, not in ChromeDriver. We are working with Chrome devs to find a solution.

[image: chrome73_issue]

---

### Solution

The solution would be to:

- Downgrade *Chrome Browser* to **Chrome v72.x**
- Use a matching *ChromeDriver* among:

  - [ChromeDriver 2.46](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/)
  - [ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=72.0.3626.69/)

> Note: If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69

---

### Outro

- Discussion: [Page.captureScreenshot no longer works in Chrome 73 under Selenium as a Service on Windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942023)
- Commit causing the issue: [Set VizDisplayCompositor feature enabled on desktop platforms](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/73a59e05c556d9bf3f9ac16dfc5f11862f08ab4b)
- Merge: 
  [latency: Remove snapshots from LatencyInfo](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1095562)
- [Download Google Chrome 72 Offline Installer For All Operating Systems](https://www.itechtics.com/download-google-chrome-72-offline-installer-for-all-operating-systems/)

---

### Update(03-April-2019)

Adding the argument `--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor` through an instance of `ChromeOptions()` seems solves the issue:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks DevanjanB. Seems like i need to downgrade the chrome version and this should work fine. Hope Chrome fixes this issue asap.

Comment: Does google offer any place to access old builds of Chrome? All I can find online are downloads from third party sites and I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: No, there are no places to access old builds of Chrome @TylerNielsen.

Comment: If you added `disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor` before, you need to remove that in Chrome 79 or this error will come back.

Comment: It is still actual with Chrome 94 (Mac). But the solution provided here as an update (Apr 2019) seems to work fine.

Comment: This is still an issue with chromedriver Version: 103.0.5060.134 adding the `VizDisplayCompositor` as above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running the same version of Chrome / Chromedriver when running headless from a Team City build. **This started after the latest update was installed on the build server on 25th March 2019.**

*The reason the screenshots were being taken in the first place, was that the tests had also started failing due to what I suspect is a related defect regarding virtual rendering in headless mode again limited to when the instance of Chrome is run via a service (TeamCity).*

The tests all run fine when I run the build script from a command prompt on the build server VM.

I resolved the issue by downgrading the chrome version. Easier said than done:

1. I couldn't find an official way to get hold of old versions of chrome, but I found this link which hosted some. Use at your own risk: 
   `https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php`
2. I downloaded version Download `version 71.0.3578.80`
3. Uninstall Chrome from build server, run this installer.
4. As soon as the update directory is created during the install process:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update`
   rename the file `GoogleUpdate.exe` to prevent it updating itself
5. Disable the Google Chrome update tasks in Task Scheduler

UPDATE: An answer here suggests the problem can be fixed with some additional arguments passed to the chromedriver, I've not tested this solution:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/38456/37816

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did it work removing

```
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
```

or using

```
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--force-device-scale-factor=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue for chromedriver 81, but I have updated to 83 so now working fine.

please try it......

Comment: we experience this occasionally on our Jenkins with Chrome 83