# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable while invoking execute_script() for Chrome Download Manager through Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267887/11220889 for waiting for downloads to finish and returning the file path once finished. And it has been working great until now.

The Function

```
def every_downloads_chrome(driver):
    if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
        driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
    return driver.execute_script('''
        var items = downloads.Manager.get().items_;
        if (items.every(e => e.state === "COMPLETE"))
            return items.map(e => e.file_url);
        ''')
```

How its called

```
paths = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)
```

Error I'm receiving

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

So from what I can gather something has changed that has started causing the function to not return a path. I believe this is due to a change within chrome or even more specifically the chrome driver. My two reasons for this assumption is:

1) I had this function in another code that my colleague was using and she called me saying it was producing this error yesterday.

2)Neither code has changed so the change must be in chrome

I would like to keep using this script but if not possible have another function that waits for the downloads to finish and returns the paths and ideally does it all through the driver not through file path since multiple users use my codes on multiple machines.

EDIT: Versions-

```
Name: selenium
Version: 3.141.0

Name: Chrome Browser
Version: 73.0.3683.86

Name: Chrome Driver
Version: 2.43.600210

Name: System
Version: Windows 10 Pro x64
```

Comment: Selenium version? WebDriver variant and version?? Client variant and version???

Comment: Edited with requested info, please let me know if this is insufficient or not what you were asking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error message:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Your main issue seems to be **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.43*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- You are using *chrome=73.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.43* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v2.46](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v73*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Update

Currently GAed ***Chrome v73*** have some issues and you may like to downgrade to ***Chrome v72***. You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Getting Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000 When we execute selenium scripts using Jenkins windows service mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373625/getting-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-600-000-when-we-execute-selen/55374585#55374585)
- [Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 while capturing screenshot using chromedriver and chrome through Jenkins on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364056/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000-while-capturing-screenshot-usi/55371396#55371396)

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I have updated the driver and am still experiencing the error so as per your suggestion what exactly do you mean by rebuild with required dependencies only?

Comment: @AG-W Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.