# Chromedriver TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Chrome` 76.0.3809.132 and `chromedriver` 76.0.1.

I am getting error while converting from HTML to PDF.

```
Chromedriver TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I once had this issue and what I referred was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397792/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable-while-invoking-execute-script?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I looked into that, but i am using correct versions, it should work with this setup?