# Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000 with Chrome v73.0, ChromeDriver 2.46 on Bamboo Server

Tags: windows, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, bamboo

After chrome browser upgraded to 73.0 selenium test are not getting executed in bamboo build server and working fine when executed locally. Upgraded compatible version of chromeDriver 2.46. Still getting error:

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1554111197.266][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Apr 01, 2019 5:33:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Force Stop build feature is enabled for current plan. Either Bamboo has detected the build has hung or it has been manually stopped.

Below is code used to launch browser:

```
public void selectBrowser(String browser)
{
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Window")) {
      if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--verbose");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips=");
        chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);
      } 
    }
}
```

Error displayed in bamboo during test execution:

[image: Please click to see bamboo error screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried adding `    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");`?

Comment: @supputuri - first time it worked after second execution getting error "[1554187619.136][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000"

Comment: Why don't you try with ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 as they fixed `Increased HTTP server listening queue length` in that version.

Answer (score 1):

[Long Story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364056/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000-while-capturing-screenshot-usi/55371396#55371396) cut [Short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373625/getting-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-600-000-when-we-execute-selen/55374585#55374585) **John Chen** (Owner - chromedriver) have confirmed that:

> The root cause is indeed in Chrome 73.x, not in ChromeDriver. We are working with Chrome devs to find a solution.

---

### Solution

A quick fix solution will be to:

- Downgrade *Chrome Browser* to **Chrome v72.x**
- Use a matching *ChromeDriver* among:

  - [ChromeDriver 2.46](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/)
  - [ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=72.0.3626.69/)

> Note: If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69

- Ensure that *JDK* is upgraded to recent level of [JDK 8u202](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

---

### Alternative

Adding the argument `--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor` through an instance of `ChromeOptions()` seems solves the issue:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

---

### Outro

You can find the relevant discussions in:

- [Page.captureScreenshot no longer works in Chrome 73 under Selenium as a Service on Windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942023)
- [Error [SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000 while executing the testsuite through Selenium on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051117/error-severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-20-000-while-executin/50051844#50051844)
- [Download Google Chrome 72 Offline Installer For All Operating Systems](https://www.itechtics.com/download-google-chrome-72-offline-installer-for-all-operating-systems/)