# Selenium Test case failed with "script returned exit code 255"

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on Selenium test case using the `chromedriver` and `mocha`. Following is the part of my `package.json` file:

```
"chromedriver": "^2.46.0",
"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"selenium-standalone": "^6.16.0",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
"webdriver-manager": "^12.1.1"
```

I am running the test cases using `ChromeDrive.exe` file having version `73.0.3686`. All test cases are running locally or throwing an error but behavior on Jenkins is totally different.

On Jenkins, I am running the following error more frequently:

```
script returned exit code 255
```

Am I missing something? Please let me know in case you need further details!

Comment: Can you cross check if `"selenium-standalone": "^6.16.0"` is a valid entry?

Comment: @DebanjanB: Can you elaborate in detail? I think I am using the latest version of `selenium-standalone` and it is `6.16.0`. Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: I don't do [tag:node.js] but haven't known about `"selenium-standalone": "^6.16.0"` while working with _Java_, _Python_ and _C#_ binding art. So I suggested to cross check.

Comment: @DebanjanB: It looks like `selenium-standalone` module is no more needed. I have removed it from the `package.json` and test case worked locally.

Answer (score 2):

As per the contents of **package.json** file, the following entry doesn't looks like a valid entry:

```
"selenium-standalone": "^6.16.0"
```

Removing this entry will address the errors.

---

However, it seems you are using **chrome=73.0.3686** on **Windows 10 Pro 64 bit**

John Chen (Owner - chromedriver) recently have confirmed that:

> We have confirmed issues with take screenshot when Chrome 73.0.3686.75 is started by a service (such as Jenkins or Task scheduler) on Windows. Please see https://crbug.com/942023 for more details. We apologize for any inconvenience caused by this.
>
> However, we haven't yet been able to observe similar issue on Linux, so we appreciate any help you can provide to enable us to reproduce the issue on Linux. We don't have access to TeamCity, but we have tested take screenshot using Docker image produced by Selenium (selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-lithium), and didn't find any problems.

---

### Solution

The solution would be to:

- Downgrade *Chrome Browser* to **Chrome v72.x**
- Use a matching *ChromeDriver* among:

  - [ChromeDriver 2.46](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/)
  - [ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=72.0.3626.69/)

> Note: If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69

As an alternative , you can add the argument `--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor` through an instance of `ChromeOptions()` seems solves the issue:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

---

### Reference

Here are the reference discussions:

- [Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 while capturing screenshot using chromedriver and chrome through Jenkins on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364056/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000-while-capturing-screenshot-usi/55371396#55371396)
- [Getting Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000 When we execute selenium scripts using Jenkins windows service mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373625/getting-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-600-000-when-we-execute-selen/55374585#55374585)

---

### Outro

- Discussion: [Page.captureScreenshot no longer works in Chrome 73 under Selenium as a Service on Windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942023)
- Commit causing the issue: [Set VizDisplayCompositor feature enabled on desktop platforms](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/73a59e05c556d9bf3f9ac16dfc5f11862f08ab4b)
- Merge: 
  [latency: Remove snapshots from LatencyInfo](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1095562)
- [Download Google Chrome 72 Offline Installer For All Operating Systems](https://www.itechtics.com/download-google-chrome-72-offline-installer-for-all-operating-systems/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But now I am getting this error on Jenkins `Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:51728/ .` Can you please guide me what should I do?

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan So, what is your _OS_ variant, **Windows**?

Comment: `Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-Bit)` and `Windows 10 Pro 64 bit`. Please let me know in case you need further details or information, I would be happy to provide you. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I appreciate it. I will get back to you soon. I hope this will help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Still I am getting this error on Jenkins `Windows Batch Script script returned exit code 255`. I have downgraded chrome version from 73 to 72 and also added the right chrome driver for it. Can you please guide me?