# Headless Chrome error when running in Jenkins for protractor scripts

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am getting below error when i run mine protractor jenkins case with below configuration

(Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.117)
[INFO]   (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.36

Code :
'chromeOptions': {

```
        'args': ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-web-security', '--disable-extensions'],
        'args': [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080" ]
    },
```

**Error:** TimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

Package.json details

```
main": "conf.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^79.0.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-cli-babel": "0.0.5",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-shell-spawn": "^0.3.8",
    "iedriver": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-allure-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.1",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.6.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000 When we execute selenium scripts using Jenkins windows service mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373625/getting-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-600-000-when-we-execute-selen)

Comment: The above issue is related to Chrome 73 and has been marked as fixed. User has already mentioned his chrome version is 79.

Comment: @sushant can you confirm if the issue is in the initial steps or after a screenshot since the issue mentioned above occurs during taking screenshot.

Comment: @demouser123 Thanks for responding, above issue happens in initial steps

Answer (score 0):

Adding the arg `--disable-dev-shm-usage` has fixed my problem.